# Unicode character is not displaying correctly in HTML page

Tags: html, unicode

I have some special unicode character which I want to display on my web page.
Here is the [Unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fdfa/index.htm)
And here is support fonts for this [Unicode](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fdfa/fontsupport.htm)

it is showing like this (ﷺ) same as it is showing in stackoverflow. Can you please let me know how can I display it

Comment: It could be an issue with the font

Comment: Stackoverflow font is `Noto`  ,Noto Naskh Arabic precisely

Comment: I tried support fonts "Arial" which is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the HTML entity `&#65018;`?

result: ﷺ

If the character still isn't displayed, you are maybe using a font which doesn't contain this character. You can switch to "Arial" temporarily to check if this is the case.

Comment: Then you are maybe using a font which doesn't contain this character. You can switch to "Arial" temporarily to check if this is the case.